# I can't find the installed app on my android virtual device

Tags: android, react-native

I'm working on an react-native app, but when try to run the app on an Android virtual device with the following command:

```
react-native run-android
```

the app run on the AVD, but I can't find the icon of the app on the virtual device, but the app run without any problem.

Here is my AndroidManifest.xml

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  package="com.local">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW"/>

    <application
      android:name=".MainApplication"
      android:label="@string/app_name"
      android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
      android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
      android:allowBackup="false"
      android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name="SplashActivity"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
      <activity
         android:name=".MainActivity"
         android:label="@string/app_name"
         android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
            android:exported="true">
        </activity>
      <activity android:name="com.facebook.react.devsupport.DevSettingsActivity" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

I don't have this problem in the iOS version.

Comment: Did you try moving the  `<intent-filter>` into `<activity android:name=".MainActivity">`?

Comment: I already tried, but same problem